# An inequality for probability measures on finite measure spaces

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $p,q$ be probability measures on a finite Borel space $X.$ Let $g$ be a real valued function on $X.$ I want to show that

$$ \bigg | \sum_w g(w)p(w) - \sum_w g(w) q(w) \bigg | \leq \frac{\sup_w g-\inf_wg}{2}\sum_w |p(w)-q(w)|.$$

I have problem with obtaining the bound with $\sup_w g- \inf_w g.$

What I've tried:
$$\bigg | \sum_w g(w)p(w)-\sum_wg(w)q(w) \bigg | = \bigg |\sum_{w \text{ s.th p(w)-q(w)>0}} g(w)(p(w)-q(w)) -\sum_{w \text{ s.th P(w)-q(w) <0}}g(w)(p(w)-q(w)) \bigg |$$
so we have
$$\bigg | \sum_w g(w)p(w)-\sum_wg(w)q(w) \bigg | \leq \bigg | \sup_w g \sum_{w \text{ s.th p(w)-q(w)>0}} (p-q)(w) - \sup_wg \sum_{w \text{ s.th (p-q)(w)<0}} (p-q)(w) \bigg |.$$
Now both $$ \sum_{w \text{ s.th p(w)-q(w)>0}} (p-q)(w) $$ and $$-\sum_{w \text{ s.th (p-q)(w)<0}} (p-q)(w)$$ are the same and equal to $\frac 12 \sum_w |p(w)-q(w)|$ but then I end up with the bound $$\frac{\sup_w g+\sup_w g}{2}.$$

This result is from pg141 of Georgii's "Gibbs measures and phase transition."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For brevity write $d(w):=p(w)-q(w)$. There is no need to carry the absolute value throughout the argument.

You wrote
$$\sum_wg(w)d(w)=\sum_{d(w)>0} g(w)d(w) - \sum_{d(w)<0}g(w)d(w)$$ but should have written
$$\sum_wg(w)d(w)=\sum_{d(w)>0} g(w)d(w) + \sum_{d(w)<0}g(w)d(w).$$ In the second sum each $d(w)$ is negative, so we have
$$\sum_{d(w)<0} g(w)d(w)= -\sum_{d(w)<0}g(w)[-d(w)]\le - \inf_wg(w)\left(\sum_{d(w)<0}[-d(w)]\right)$$ and therefore
$$\sum_w g(w)d(w)\le \sup_wg(w)\left(\sum_{d(w)>0}d(w) \right)- \inf_wg(w)\left(\sum_{d(w)<0}[-d(w)]\right).$$ Now continue with your argument, noting that $$\sum_{d(w)>0}d(w)=-\sum_{d(w)<0}d(w)=\frac12\sum_w|d(w)|.$$

Comment: Oh god. Thanks alot. I can't believe I made such a mistake and didn't notice it for hours. Many thanks.